# FCKEditor with Rails Security Vulnerability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fckeditor, html-safe

I am using FCKEditor in my Ruby on Rails Application. Users add blog posts using FCKEditor.

Then I display blog posts using

```
@blog.body.html_safe
```

I know FCKEditor is escaping any javascript code but what if a user posted a request with direct parameters and setting blog post body including some javascripts. This may be security Vulnerability.

Any idea how can I used FCKEditor with Rails safe?

Comment: html_safe should be escaping javascript already, regardless of what FCKEditor is doing? Could you provide more details of what you see as a potential exploit?

Comment: Joe is right, you really aren't relying on FCKEditor to do the security, html_safe is what does that.  Additionally, FCKEditor is out of date, you should seriously consider moving to CKEditor (New version of FCKEditor, they changed the name for obvious reasons).

Comment: No Joe, html_safe doesn't escape javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use white list HTML sanitizer to escape all tags except some formatting tags.

[Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/)